# why does Powershell Test-Path -Isvalid always returns true

Tags: powershell

based on documentation -IsValid is supposed to check if the syntax of the path is correct. Anything i put for the Test-Path it always return true

> Indicates that this cmdlet tests the syntax of the path, regardless of
>   whether the elements of the path exist. This cmdlet returns $True if
>   the path syntax is valid and $False if it is not

```
$val = Test-Path "sadfasdasdfasdf" -IsValid
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may certainly look like everything goes, but that's not the case. The `-IsValid` only does syntax check. There's nothing wrong with the syntax: `"sadfasdasdfasdf"` could very well be a subdirectory within current directory.

For example, the following paths are using incorrect syntax and thus not valid:

```
PS C:\> Test-Path "foo>bar" -IsValid # Redirection in path
False
PS C:\> Test-Path "foo:bar" -IsValid # Edge case, HKLM:USER would be valid
False
PS C:\> Test-Path "foo|bar" -IsValid # Pipe in path
False
```